# How to get selected only single checkbox from multiple checkboxes using ionic 2 and angular2

Tags: checkbox, angular, typescript, ionic2

Presently working on ionic2 and angular2 
I am having fields of 7 checkboxes. I need to select only one particular checkbox the remaining checkboxes should be disabled.Similarly, I need to get for remaining 6 checkboxes also. How can I do that, 
Here is the code I have used in my HTML

// payment.HTML

```
<ion-card class="ion-card">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Cash On Delivery</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox item-right checked="true" [(ngModel)]="checked"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item no-lines>
            <ion-label>PayuMoney Wallet</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox item-right  checked="false" [(ngModel)]="checked"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item no-lines>
            <ion-label>Pay with Paytm Wallet</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox item-right checked="false" [(ngModel)]="checked"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item no-lines>
            <ion-label>Credit/ Debit Card</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox item-right checked="false" [(ngModel)]="checked"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item no-lines>
            <ion-label>Net Banking</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox item-right checked="false" [(ngModel)]="checked"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item no-lines>
            <ion-label>PayZapp</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox item-right checked="false" [(ngModel)]="checked"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item no-lines>
            <ion-label>Pay using MobiKwiK Wallet</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox item-right checked="false" [(ngModel)]="checked"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>

    </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might do what you want (not tested):

```
<ion-card class="ion-card">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of options; let i=index">
    <ion-label>{{item}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox item-right [ngModel]="checkedIdx == i"(ngModelChange)="$event ? checkedIdx = i : checkedIdx = -1" [disabled]="checkedIdx >= 0 && checkedIdx != i"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

```
class MyComponent {
  checkedIdx=0;

  options = [
    'Cash On Delivery',
    'PayuMoney Wallet',
    'Pay with Paytm Wallet',
    'Credit/ Debit Card',
    'Net Banking',
    'PayZapp',
    'Pay using MobiKwiK Wallet'
  ];
}
```

Comment: I tried this,I need to select only one check box. If i select first check box the remaining 6 checkboxes should be disabled. How can i do that

Comment: I don't understand "Similarly, I need to get for remaining 6 checkboxes also". Wouldn't a radio button work better for your use case?

Comment: yes you are right but my requirement is to have the check box i am new to  ionic framework. What i think is to invoke a funtion each time i click the check box is there any other option many function

Comment: this solution show first option enabled and other options disabled at first view. if you want to show all boxes enabled at first view just change     checkedIdx=0; to checkedIdx=-1;  (tested and verified)