# Allow only one selection of check while other option disable in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, ionic3

I have been following this solution

[How to get selected only single checkbox from multiple checkboxes using ionic 2 and angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39363696/9669068)
its working fine but the issue is

When i check any checkbox the other gets disabled (which is what i want) but if i uncheck the same checkbox the other still remains disabled. How do i enable them after the checkbox is unchecked?

here is my code 
.ts file

```
export class list {
checkedIdx = -1;
}
```

.html file

```
<ion-card class="ion-card">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of options; let i=index">
    <ion-label>{{item}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox item-left [ngModel]="checkedIdx == i"(ngModelChange)="$event ? checkedIdx = i : checkedIdx = -1" [disabled]="checkedIdx >= 0 && checkedIdx != i"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **CHECK** [**WORKING STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-select-one-checkbox-at-a-time)

### Only one checkbox can be selected at a time

Your **`component.html`** should be something like this:~

```
<ion-card class="ion-card">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index">
        <ion-label>{{category.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox 
    [disabled]="categories[i].value" 
    (click)="selection(category.name);">
        </ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

And your **`component.ts`** can be something like this:~

```
  selection(name: string) {
    this.categories.forEach(x => {
      if (x.name !== name) {
        x.value = !x.value
      }
    })
  }
```

Hope this is helpful !

Comment: How to disable the first one checkbox only when the second checkbox is pressed?